# using fscanf from a file to bool variables and coverity run

Tags: c, scanf

In my project i am currently using `fscanf(fp, "%d ",&deviceId))` where `fp` is the file pointer and deviceId is a `BOOL` variable. Once i run the coverity tool(static analysis), i am getting a warning as shown below:

> **CID 11375 (#1 of 1): Calling risky function (SECURE_CODING)
>   secure_coding: [VERY RISKY]. Using "fscanf" can cause a buffer overflow when done incorrectly. fscanf() assumes an arbitrarily large string, so callers must use correct precision specifiers or never use fscanf(). Use correct precision specifiers or do your own parsing.**

Is there anyway to resolve this defect as i cant change the use of fscanf. Any format specifiers would work?

Comment: It seems like a note about string mainly.

Comment: The `*scanf()` function family is generally limited in its ability to recover facing malformed input. Generally speaking, you are better off reading input into internal buffers using other functions (like `fread()` or `fgets()`), then parsing the input from there using more robust functions with better recovery abilities (like `strtol()`).

Comment: What is `BOOL`? This is not a standard type.

Answer (score 2):

Static analysers always give floods of false warnings. In this case, your particular static analyser is likely checking the code against some given code standard that bans the use of fscanf no matter the input to it, for the reasons mentioned in the warning.

You have to know which code standard(s) you are checking against and why. You have apparently decided to apply a coding standard that bans fscanf, yet you insist on using that function.

So nobody else can solve this problem for you. You need to either create a deviation from that rule if your coding standard allows deviations, or you have to stop using fscanf, or you have to pick a coding standard/tool that makes sense to your application.

Answer (score 1):

As Lundin said, the coding standard you enabled by using the SECURE_CODING defects is quite stringent and does not allow even for benign cases like yours.

In general, it's a bad idea to blindly enable all checkers from a static analysis tool... some are very much FP prone (like this SECURE_CODING) and almost pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right, it's not a defect - coverity warns for use of `fscanf` and won't make an exception even if you're using it fine.

It would indeed be potentially risky if you had used `%s` format.